# How to stretch 1ns pulse into a 5ns pulse?

Tags: rf, pulse, monostable

We have a time-tagger device that records the arrival of a LVTTL signal with 0.5ns resolution.  Currently the 5ns LVTTL signal is generated by a separate commercial Avalanche Photon Diode but I would like to replace that with an in-house SiPM (https://www.sensl.com/downloads/ds/DS-MicroCseries.pdf)

The fast output of the SiPM generates a pulse that has a 1ns rise time and 1ns width.  Is there a simple way to convert this to a 5ns, 3.3V pulse?  I was hoping there would be a monostable multivibrator IC that could do the job but I couldn't find anything that fast.

Many thanks for any guidance provided...

Comment: Please edit your question and add a schematic. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: What are you using for an amplifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need a really fast comparator and a pulse stretcher circuit. For stretching the pulse (which is your question here) once you get it into logic level voltages, I think you could use a [SN74AUC74](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74auc74.pdf) and feed the output back to the /CLR input through a delay.

It's not safely capable of handling your high voltage 3.3V supply but that could be dealt with in one or more ways. With a 1.8-2.7V supply it is guaranteed to respond to a 500ps pulse.